# Update EmberJS SortableMixin Based Component on content change

Tags: ember.js

i have a simple component that extends Ember.SortableMixin:

```
export default Ember.Component.extend(Ember.SortableMixin, {
    sortProperties:  ['points:DESC']
})
```

It displays points and name:

```
{{#each arrangedContent as |user index|}}
    {{user.name}} {{user.points}}
{{/each}}
```

and its included like this:

```
{{quiz-leaderboard content=model.participants}}
```

If the points now changes there are updated in the view, but the sorting is not refreshed. How can i manage this?
Thanks for any help, Jan

Comment: your question is not clear, how did you defined  'arrangedContent' ? can you show some more code ?

Comment: Hi Anil, arrangedContent is a property of the SortableMixin: 
[link](http://ember-doc.com/classes/Ember.SortableMixin.html#property_arrangedContent). Following the docs this should also set up observers to all item properties that are used for sorting.

Comment: In fact it works if i set the data in the ember inspector. So its probably a bug in the rest of the code.. Thanks anyway!

Answer (score 0):

It will work out of the box, as the SortableMixin will add observers to all properties. Note that this will not work on a construct like this:

```
  sortProperties:  ['points:DESC']
```

As a workaround i just used

```
 sortProperties:  ['points']
```

and set the

```
sortAscendingBoolean
```

property.

Comment: There already seems to be a pending fi: https://github.com/kagemusha/ember.js/commit/8a4adc4ff29e638742825a20bacca33910741616

Answer (score 0):

Using Ember.SortableMixin, you need to declare the properties you wish to sort on and the order separately.

```
sortProperties: ['points'],
sortAscending: false,
```

Sauce: http://emberjs.com/api/classes/Ember.SortableMixin.html#property_sortAscending